# Expression Engine categories channel outputting empty list

Tags: list, duplicates, expressionengine, categories

I have a problem with outputting categories in to a list.
It seems to create another ul(one for the channel:categories) within the my ul, and also creates empty lists before each list.

I used the exact same code for entries and it worked fine. 
Is this a categories problem?

Here is the Code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a {if segment_2 == ""} class="selected" {/if} href="">News &amp; Events</a></li>       

    {exp:channel:categories
            channel="news_events"
            disable="pagination|member_data|trackbacks"
            dynamic="no"}

            <li><a href="">{category_name}</a></li>
        {/exp:channel:categories}

    <li><a {if segment_2 == "gallery"} class="selected"{/if} href="">Image Gallery</a></li>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regard to the code output, take a look at the `style` parameter for the channel categories tag: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/categories.html#channel-categories-style. You'll want to change it to `style="linear"` to use your own markup.

As for the blank output, it's going to be tough to diagnose without seeing your install but try getting rid of `dynamic="no"`.

Comment: I used style="linear" and it got rid of the ul and the empty lists. Thanks so much!